# Search trough html content to return specific tag using php

Tags: php, html

i have this in php

```
$url = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="waitmsg" id="WaitMessage" style="display:none">
        <WaitMessage>Transaction Processing, Please Wait...</WaitMessage>
    </div>
    <form id="mpiRun" action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="dest" value="33777" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="one" value="102900" /> 
        <br>      
        <br>
        <noscript>      
            <center>      
                <h1>Processing Transaction</h1>
                <input type="submit" />      
            </center>
        </noscript>
    </form>
</body>
</html>';
```

Is there a way using php i can get

```
$result = '<form id="mpiRun" action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="dest" value="33777" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="one" value="102900" /> 
        <br>      
        <br>
        <noscript>      
            <center>      
                <h1>Processing Transaction</h1>
                <input type="submit" />      
            </center>
        </noscript>
    </form>';
```

If it can not be done using php, what other ways can it be achieved. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check it. It will work

Answer (score 2):

For this question, this should work.

```
$start = strpos($url,"<form");
$end = strpos($url,"</form>");
$len = $end - $start;
$result = substr($url,$start,$len);
```

Now, `$result` contains what you want.
Find starting position of `<form>` and `</form>` and store the substring in `$result`.